# How to iterate through rows of a dataframe and check whether value in a column row is NaN

Tags: python, pandas, iteration, row, dataframe

I have a beginner question. I have a dataframe I am iterating over and I want to check if a value in a column2 row is `NaN` or not, to perform an action on this value if it is not `NaN`. My DataFrame looks like this:

```
df:

  Column1  Column2
0    a        hey
1    b        NaN
2    c        up
```

What I am trying right now is:

```
for item, frame in df['Column2'].iteritems():
    if frame.notnull() == True:
        print 'frame'
```

The thought behind that is that I iterate over the rows in column 2 and `print` frame for every row that has a value (which is a string). What I get however is this:

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-80-8b871a452417> in <module>()
      1 for item, frame in df['Column2'].iteritems():
----> 2     if frame.notnull() == True:
      3         print 'frame'

AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'notnull'
```

When I only run the first line of my code, I get

```
0
hey
1
nan
2
up
```

which suggests that the floats in the output of the first line are the cause of the error. Can anybody tell me how I can accomplish what I want?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As you already understand , `frame` in

```
for item, frame in df['Column2'].iteritems():
```

is every `row` in the Column, its type would be the type of elements in the column (which most probably would not be `Series` or `DataFrame`). Hence, `frame.notnull()` on that would not work.

You should instead try -

```
for item, frame in df['Column2'].iteritems():
    if pd.notnull(frame):
        print frame
```

Comment: It works in terms that only the frames (rows) are printed, but the `nan` values are still present.. But why are the frame values floats when they should be strings?

Comment: Pandas represents all missing values as the floating-point number `nan`

Comment: You can use `pd.notnull()` to check if the value is not `NaN` . If you want to also filter out empty strings/ None values, you can also do - `if frame and pd.notnull(frame):` .

Comment: @AnandSKumar Okay, this works. I think I called .notnull() wrong when I tried that before. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 4):

try this:

```
df[df['Column2'].notnull()]
```

The above code will give you the data for which `Column2` has not null value

Answer (score 1):

Using `iteritems` on a Series (which is what you get when you take a column from a DataFrame) iterates over pairs (index, value). So your `item` will take the values 0, 1, and 2 in the three iterations of the loop, and your `frame` will take the values `'hey'`, `NaN`, and `'up'` (so "frame" is probably a bad name for it). The error comes from trying to use the method `notnull` on `NaN` (which is represented as a floating-point number).

You can use the function `pd.notnull` instead:

```
In [3]: pd.notnull(np.nan)
Out[3]: False

In [4]: pd.notnull('hey')
Out[4]: True
```

Another way would be to use `notnull` on the whole Series, and then iterate over those values (which are now boolean):

```
for _, value in df['Column2'].notnull().iteritems():
    if value:
        print 'frame'
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation of the error, I didn't know that nan was presented as floating point!